# How do I set the ODBC connection string in VS2022?

Tags: odbc, connection-string, visual-studio-2022

I have an app with a combobox where the user can select the Database they want to connect to. Populating the list from the app.config works fine.  On the FetchData function, I try to set the ODBC connectionstring according to which database the user selected.

```
            int selectedDB = cbxDatabase.SelectedIndex;
            string connectionstring = dbconnections[selectedDB].ConnectionString;
            /*string connectionstring = Properties.Settings.Default.connString;*/
            MessageBox.Show(selectedDB.ToString());
            MessageBox.Show(connectionstring);
```

For some reason, it keeps connecting to the first connectstring, regardless of which database I select. The selected index is correct, but the connection string still defaults to whatever is in index 0. I'm testing the code in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out...

changed the connectionstring line to:

```
string connectionstring = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[cbxDatabase.Text].ConnectionString.ToString();
```